# Передача ImageView в другое Activity

Tags: java

Как сделать передачу содержимого ImageView из одного активити в другое, и при этом возможность сохранять и очищать переданное ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать статический экземпляр ImageView, желательно вне активити и пользоваться им, а вообще лучше хранить изображение, или его ури, и передавать ссылку на него, а не экземпляр view